# Do I need to open all three ports for my Bedrock server?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

Minecraft Bedrock Alpha Server requires me to open the following ports (default):

- TCP: 19132
- TCP: 19133 (IPv6)
- UDP: 19132 (to check if a server is    online, afaik)

Would it be enough to only keep TCP 19132 open (none of my mates uses IPv6)? If the UDP one is only for checking if a server is online or not without joining, I think that one can be omitted too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it with the help of a remote friend.

If you want an IPv4-only server, you NEED to have 19132 open as UDP and TCP port. Using only one of both will not work.

I think most of you will not use IPv6, so you can probably ignore it.